# Python group and calculate

Tags: python, python-3.x

I try to group and sum different python list by payment method:

My list looks like this:

```
['Card payment', 'Cash', 'Rounding'][2000.0, 101.05, -0.01]
['Cash'][750.0]
['Cash', 'Cash'][-2578.15, 3333.0]
['Card payment', 'Cash', 'Rounding'][2000.0, 101.05, -0.01]
['Card payment'][313.6]
```

I would like them to be calculated to variables like this:

```
cash_payment = (total amount of the cash payments)
card_payment = (total amount of the card payments)
rounding = (total amount of rounding)
```

What is the best way to do this?

I have a version with multiple if/elif cases but the has to be a better way.

The code i have:

```
    if payment_journal_name == card or payment_journal_name == cash:
        if payment_journal_name[0] == card and payment_journal_name[1] == cash:
            card_payment = payment_journal_amount[0] + card_payment
            cash_payment = payment_journal_amount[1] + cash_payment
        elif payment_journal_name[0] == cash and payment_journal_name[1] == cash and payment_journal_name[2] == rounding:
            cash_payment = pr.amount_total + cash_payment + rounded_total
        elif payment_journal_name[0] == cash and payment_journal_name[1] == cash:
            cash_payment = pr.amount_total + cash_payment
        elif payment_journal_name[0] == card:
            card_payment = pr.amount_total + card_payment

    elif payment_journal_name[0] == card:
        card_payment = pr.amount_total + card_payment
    elif payment_journal_name[0] == cash:
        cash_payment = pr.amount_total + cash_payment
```

**SOLUTION**

```
    for method, amount in zip(payment_journal_name, payment_journal_amount):
        if method == cash:
            cash_payment = amount + cash_payment
        elif method == card:
            card_payment = amount + card_payment
        elif method == rounding:
            rounding_payment = amount + rounding_payment
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and correct the syntax of the list. As it is now, it's not valid in Python. You can also add code what have you tried so far.

Comment: Its 2 arrays next to each other.

Comment: Please try to update your question with usable python code, like in the accepted answer. That would help others understanding both the question and the answer. I will remove the Odoo tag, because there is no real relevance to Odoo here, it's more a normal python problem ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if you are trying to iterate over two lists one item at a time I would suggest the zip function (built-in):

```
l1 = ['Card payment', 'Cash', 'Rounding']
l2 = [2000.0, 101.05, -0.01]

for method, amount in zip(l1, l2):
    print(f'{method}: {amount}')
```

#### Output:

> Card payment: 2000.0
>   Cash: 101.05
>   Rounding: -0.01

This will work especially well if the two lists are of the same length. Otherwide the loop will stop when the last item of the shortest list is reached.
If your lists are not going of the same length I recommend using the zip_longest fonction from the itertools module (stdlib) which will continue looping until it reaches the end of the longest list. In this case all the missing items of the shortest list will be replaced by None.

Comment: Thank you! The problem is that the length varies from payment to payment. Will try this and post my version.

Comment: What I mean is that as long as there as many items in the payment method list as there are in the amount list the it will work no problem

Comment: Oh, i see! Thanks! I still have problem to get the data to correct variables. How should i do it?

Comment: What do you mean? if your data is formatted as it is in my example (which is taken from your example) this will work without an issue and without any further work

Comment: I mean in the for loop i would like to the payments to correct variabels: card_payment = 2000.0, cash_payment  = 101.05 and rounding = -0.01.

Comment: I see. Well i can't see your entire program from what I see it seems to me you need to rework the way you store your data. Maybe a list per payment method? `cash = [530, 220, ...]`, `card = [2000, 351, ...]` something like this seems efficient

Comment: Thanks for all the help! I solved it with your answers! :)